# How does Wireshark resolve DNS names?

Tags: dns, wireshark

Could you explain how Wireshark makes a DNS query in order to resolve the name of an IP address?

My issue is about the mismatch between the domain name resolved by Wireshark and that returned by `nslookup`.  Moreover, `nslookup` sometimes fails for certain IP addresses where Wireshark succeeds.

An example in order to clarify:
A case I found (one of thousands) is about the address 54.230.45.185

Wireshark resolves it as: `dwjgneh8ogcu1.cloudfront.net` (54.230.45.185) (yes, it seems to be a randomly generated domain name)

The other tools resolve it differently, something like:
`server-54-230-45-185.fra6.r.cloudfront.net`

So I'm wondering how or where Wireshark finds that domain name.

Another example is: `installer.betterinstaller.com` (78.138.127.15).

Answer (score 2):

If you open the "Edit" tab and select "Preferences", there is a section called "Name resolution".

According to the mouse-over hints, it uses its own host file, your hosts file, DNS packets in the capture, and your system's configured DNS server

Comment: See also : https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/37680/can-wireshark-automatically-resolve-the-ip-address-into-host-names

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the operation system:

> Wireshark will ask the operating system (or the concurrent DNS library), to convert an IP address to the hostname associated with it (e.g. 216.239.37.99 → www.1.google.com). The DNS service is using synchronous calls to the DNS server. So Wireshark will stop responding until a response to a DNS request is returned. If possible, you might consider using the concurrent DNS library (which won’t wait for a name server response).

For example: Linux: `host` - Windows: `nslookup` or even `ping`

[Source](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvNameResolutionSection.html)

Answer (score 1):

From the Wireshark documentation which should answer your first question:

"DNS/concurrent DNS name resolution (system/library service): Wireshark will ask the operating system (or the concurrent DNS library), to convert an IP address to the hostname associated with it (e.g. 216.239.37.99 → www.1.google.com). The DNS service is using synchronous calls to the DNS server. So Wireshark will stop responding until a response to a DNS request is returned. If possible, you might consider using the concurrent DNS library (which won’t wait for a name server response)."

I don't have any experience personally with nslookup producing different results than Wireshark's name resolution. Can you please produce a specific example and elaborate?